# [BotFramework]: How to capture/extract the values submitted through Adaptive card rendered in C# Web Chat bot in a waterfall dialog?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

I have chatbot created in C# using SDK 4 which has multiple dialog's each dialog calls another, in one dialog i am rendering Adaptive card in STEP #1 which is having only 2 inputs be provided with OK button:
1. Date
2. Time
3. OK Button
So that i can take the extract/captures the values submitted through OK button in STEP#2 and continue with process.

Issue: How to extract the values that has been submitted in step#1 in STEP#2 in an waterfall dialog in C#?

Language: C#

Bot SDK: V4

Please help as i am new to BOT and coding by providing step by step guide?

I have already tried few things like:
1. Putting the card rendered in prompt
2. Try to extract/capture value through:
stepContext.Context.Activity.Value

All of this did not help.

STEP #1: 
`var cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(this.cards);`
`var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();`
`reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment };`
`return await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply);`
// or
`return await stepContext.PromptAsync("datetextPrompt", new PromptOptions()`
 `{`
`Prompt = reply,`
 `});`

STEP #2:
I want to extract or capture value? How to do it?

Comment: Adaptive Cards are not really supported yet in waterfall dialogs. This is the [GitHub issue] (https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/614) track for this request. There are some solutions involving creating your own card prompt such as the one discuss [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009106/adaptive-card-response-from-a-waterfallstep-dialog-ms-bot-framework-v4)

Comment: @EdBoykin Clarification: Adaptive cards are absolutely supported in waterfall dialogs. They just can't currently be used as prompts, since that wasn't really their original intent. They can still be displayed, however.

Comment: I agree. I should have been more clear on my statement. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using Adaptive Cards with [Waterfall Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#waterfall-dialogs)**

Natively, Adaptive Cards don't work like prompts. With a prompt, the prompt will display and wait for user input before continuing. But with Adaptive Cards (even if it contains an input box and a submit button), there is no code in an Adaptive Card that will cause a Waterfall Dialog to wait for user input before continuing the dialog.

So, if you're using an Adaptive Card that takes user input, you generally want to handle whatever the user submits outside of the context of a Waterfall Dialog.

That being said, if you want to use an Adaptive Card as part of a Waterfall Dialog, there is a workaround. Basically, you:

1. Display the Adaptive Card
2. Display a Text Prompt
3. Convert the user's Adaptive Card input into the input of a Text Prompt

In your Waterfall Dialog class (steps 1 and 2):

```
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DisplayCardAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Display the Adaptive Card
        var cardPath = Path.Combine(".", "AdaptiveCard.json");
        var cardJson = File.ReadAllText(cardPath);
        var cardAttachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardJson),
        };
        var message = MessageFactory.Text("");
        message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment };
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);

        // Create the text prompt
        var opts = new PromptOptions
        {
            Prompt = new Activity
            {
                Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
                Text = "waiting for user input...", // You can comment this out if you don't want to display any text. Still works.
            }
        };

        // Display a Text Prompt and wait for input
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), opts);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> HandleResponseAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Do something with step.result
        // Adaptive Card submissions are objects, so you likely need to JObject.Parse(step.result)
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"INPUT: {stepContext.Result}");
        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
    }
```

In your main bot class (`<your-bot>.cs`), under `OnTurnAsync()`, near the beginning of the method, somewhere before `await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken)` is called (step 3):

```cs
var activity = turnContext.Activity;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(activity.Text) && activity.Value != null)
{
    activity.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.Value);
}
```

#### Additional Context

Adaptive Cards send their Submit results a little different than regular user text. When a user types in the chat and sends a normal message, it ends up in `Context.Activity.Text`. When a user fills out an input on an Adaptive Card, it ends up in `Context.Activity.Value`, which is an object where the key names are the `id` in your card and the values are the field values in the adaptive card.

For example, the json:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Test Adaptive Card"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Text:"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 20
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "userText",
                            "placeholder": "Enter Some Text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": 80
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

.. creates a card that looks like:

[image: Test Adaptive Card]

If a user enters "Testing Testing 123" in the text box and hits Submit, `Context.Activity` will look something like:

```
{ type: 'message',
  value: { userText: 'Testing Testing 123' },
  from: { id: 'xxxxxxxx-05d4-478a-9daa-9b18c79bb66b', name: 'User' },
  locale: '',
  channelData: { postback: true },
  channelId: 'emulator',
  conversation: { id: 'xxxxxxxx-182b-11e9-be61-091ac0e3a4ac|livechat' },
  id: 'xxxxxxxx-182b-11e9-ad8e-63b45e3ebfa7',
  localTimestamp: 2019-01-14T18:39:21.000Z,
  recipient: { id: '1', name: 'Bot', role: 'bot' },
  timestamp: 2019-01-14T18:39:21.773Z,
  serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:58453' }
```

The user submission can be seen in `Context.Activity.Value.userText`.

Note that adaptive card submissions are sent as a postBack, which means that the submission data doesn't appear in the chat window as part of the conversation--it stays on the Adaptive Card.

Comment: Thanks Richardson, but since a i am bit new to coding and bot can you please let me know the following?
1. how are you getting/how to get  this method is GetReplyFromCardAsync in         var reply = await stepContext.Context.Activity.GetReplyFromCardAsync("BusinessyForm"); When i tried this i did not get the method?
2. What is the value "BusinessyForm" we are passing in the method GetReplyFromCardAsync "? Is the adaptive card json file?
3. And what does the method GetReplyFromCardAsync  do and how to access it using Context.Activity?

Comment: @ChaitanyaNG I apologize. I copy/pasted the answer from another answer I've provided before and didn't proof-read it close enough. That method was something specific to their code. Instead, use `stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply()`, which I've edited into my answer

Comment: Hi Richardson,Apology for the delay in reply as i was in vacation so couldn't reply back asap. I have tired what you have explained in water fall dialog:
1. Step 1: I wrote the code of displaying the adaptive card as given by you i..e displaying the Adaptive card
2. Step 2:  The below as explained by you:
 await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"INPUT: {stepContext.Result}");
        return await stepContext.NextAsync();
3. Then In OnTurnSync method after initializing dialog context wrote code of Postback activity. But no luck, still the same issue.Please help.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNG No problem. Can you edit your question with your code? It will help me see what's going wrong. Or, if you can post a link to your repo, that would work, too.

Comment: Hi Richardson, Thanks for your time again. I have uplaoded my solution in ZIP file in following GIT Repo: https://github.com/chaitanya116/AdaptivecardDatainV4Chatbot.git

Please let me know if you have issues with the file. Please guide me step by step if i had done anything wrong with my code.
Thanks for your help again.

Comment: The issue with the code that you sent is that you haven't added a Text Prompt. This is causing the Text Prompt to not be displayed, so it isn't capturing the user input appropriately. In `FormFlowExampleBotBot.cs`, add `dialogs.Add(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));` to the constructor.

Comment: Hi Richardson, This worked thanks for all the help,time and baring with me in correcting my mistakes in the code. Thanks a LOT.

Comment: @mdrichardson I've got a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588668/capture-values-submitted-by-adaptive-card-in-waterfall-dialog), I feel like I am overlooking something obvious.. A second pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated. :-D