# How send event from botframework v3 c# and listen at client side javascript using Direct Line?

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

How to disable user input by using disabled at wc-shellinput only when some event fires from MessagesController or from any dialog and enable it when desired action accomplished by user.
What if I want to navigate web app during conversation with chatbot?
How this type of event handling possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s how you can get it running, based off of [this WebChat sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.b.incoming-activity-event):

#### Add custom ChannelData to your outgoing activity (in bot code)

See [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/core-ChannelData) for more info.

```cs
var message = context.MakeMessage();
```

**To Disable Input**

```cs
message.ChannelData = new { chatBox = "disable" }
```

**To Enable Input**

```cs
message.ChannelData = new { chatBox = "enable" }
```

**Send the message**

```cs
await context.PostAsync(message);
```

#### Create the event for `channelData.chatBox` (in index.html script tags)

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
    {},
    ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    if (action && action.payload && action.payload.activity && action.payload.activity.channelData && action.payload.activity.channelData.chatBox) {
        const event = new Event(`chatBox`);
        event.data = action.payload.activity.channelData.chatBox;
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    return next(action);
    }
);
```

#### Listen for event and enable/disable the chat box (in index.html script tags)

```js
window.addEventListener('chatBox', ({ data }) => {
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(`[data-id="webchat-sendbox-input"]`);
    switch(data){
        case 'enable':
            chatBox.disabled = false;
            break;
        case 'disable':
            chatBox.disabled = true;
            break;
    }
});
```

**Enabled:**

[image]

**Disabled:**

[image]

Just be sure you ensure you re-enable it after disabling, as needed!

#### With BotChat

It's pretty much the same thing. You're reporting that BotChat isn't detecting all messages, so I used events instead.

**Create/send events**

```cs
var disable = new Activity()
{
    Type = ActivityTypes.Event,
    Value = new { chatBox = "disable" }
};
var enable = new Activity()
{
    Type = ActivityTypes.Event,
    Value = new { chatBox = "enable" }
};
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(disable);
```

**Listen for events in BotChat**

```js
botConnection.activity$
    .subscribe(function (activity) {
        if (activity.type === 'event' && activity.value.chatBox) {
            controlInput(activity.value.chatBox);
        }
    });

    function controlInput(action) {
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(`[class="wc-shellinput"]`);
    switch(action) {
        case 'enable':
            chatBox.disabled = false;
            break;
        case 'disable':
            chatBox.disabled = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Note: If you're using the standard BotChat css, the input color doesn't change. You'll need to add the css yourself. Something along the lines of:

```css
input:disabled {
          background-color: black !important;
      }
```

Comment: thanks bro, but I'm using botchat.js and Ised this method to get identify message activities but problem is getting only first few logs of welcome message not whole message
`botConnection.activity$
    .subscribe(function(activity){
        if(activity.type == "message"){
            console.log(activity.type)
        }
    });`

Comment: I see. How difficult would it be for you to switch to WebChat (where I know this is possible)? I can attempt this in botchat, but if you're going to switch anyway, I won't worry about it.

Comment: @MuhammadAsimZaman I've added a solution for BotChat. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @mdrichardson, Actually I was using customize css that's why don't want to switch but yesterday I switched to webchat.js...
I want to customize buttons and other things according to requirement of project of can we dynamically change the properties of buttons lets suppose In one case I want to change button color and shape which should be different In other case, how to customize in webchat.js...

Comment: In root dialog StartAsync method I called ShowAccountCard
`private async Task ShowAccountCard(IDialogContext context){  
 Attachment attachment = new Attachment(){
       Content = await GetCardText("accountOptions"),
       ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType
};    
   var message = context.MakeMessage();
   message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    await context.PostAsync(message);          
   context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync1);
}`
Card displayed but MessageReceivedAsync1 called without getting user input and clicking on submit why?

Comment: @MuhammadAsimZaman See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004289/botframework-how-to-capture-extract-the-values-submitted-through-adaptive-car/56010355#56010355). Cards, even with inputs don't wait like prompts. You need a blank text prompt after to force a wait and capture input. FYI: We monitor the `botframework` tag every morning, so feel free to submit as a separate question if you're stuck and we'll help you!