# How to extract the text from a message card - Bot Composer

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I have created my own middleware to extract the conversation between the bot and the user using OnturnAsync, but I cannot extract the text from a card sent by the bot. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[BotFramework\]: How to capture/extract the values submitted through Adaptive card rendered in C# Web Chat bot in a waterfall dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004289/botframework-how-to-capture-extract-the-values-submitted-through-adaptive-car)